# How serious are these cracks in drywall and foundation?

Tags: drywall, concrete, foundation, structural, crack

I just bought this 20yr old house a year ago and now I am noticing crack indoor as well as on the foundation.
[image]

Indoor crack goes all the way across the ridge of the angled wall and down to the corner where marked in red.

Outside crack looks like this.
[image]

Indoor crack looks a lot like what they call matching vertical crack?
I have "differential movement" of front stoop and back patio as well.
Am I in trouble?

Comment: is your house a double wide manufactured home?

Comment: No it's not. It's not and this is the backside of the house. It's an open living room

Answer (score 1):

I think you already know the answer. I'm not in construction but have seen many homes and made a lot of ceiling drywall repairs. I've never seen a ceiling crack & separate that much. And Foundation cracks! Think you need an on site inspection to find out exactly what's going on. It can be fixed. Either esthetically, correctly or both. But be ready for the cost to do it right. Good luck.